# Sum values depending other column

Tags: excel, sum

I have 3 excel sheets.
In `Sheet 1` I have 3 columns:

- order number
- agent And
- order value.

In the `Sheet 2` I have only 1 column with order numbers.
In the third `sheet` I have 2 columns:

- agent and
- total orders values.

I want to `sum` `Order values` for every `Agent` (on `sheet 3`), BUT only if `order numbers` from `sheet 1` contains `order number` from `sheet 2`.
What function should I use? Is there some function like `"Contains"` in `excel`?
I tried `countif` but I cannot write it in one function..

Comment: Have you tried `SUMIFS`? [Sum values based on multiple conditions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/sum-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-HA102809345.aspx)

Comment: @elimad
Yes i tried. I added the agent name criteria, but can't find the way to add the order number criteria.
When i add this criteria i'm getting the value of ONE row only

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your data architecture.

On Sheet1 add a column with a formula that checks if the current row's order number exists in Sheet2, like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"include","exclude")
```

[image]

Now you can build a pivot table in Sheet3 based on the data in Sheet1. Drag the Agent into the rows, the order value into the Values and the sheet2Order into the Filters. Set that filter to "include".

[image]